# Security risks of a link scraping system

Tags: python, security, http

I'm implementing a link scraping system like Facebook's link share feature, whereby a user enters a url which is passed to our server via ajax, and our server then does a get request (using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/index.html) library) and parses the response html with [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to capture relevant information about the page.

In this type of system, obviously a person can enter any url that they want. I'm trying to imagine what type of security risks our server could be exposed to in this type of scenario? Could such a set up be exploited maliciously?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make sure that your server doesn't execute any plugins or copy any videos/images.

Javascript is trickier, if you ignore it you will miss some links, if you execute it then you had better be sure you aren't being used to do something like send spam.

If you are asking on SO you probably aren't sure enough!

Comment: You're best off not attempting to execute any JavaScript due to the risk involved.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a google on [RFI/LFI](http://0xzoidberg.wordpress.com/category/security/lfi-rfi/) (Remote / Local) File Inclusion Vulnerability and [Iframe](http://www.breakthesecurity.com/2011/07/what-is-iframe-injection-mass-iframe.html) attacks. If you are safe from these two attacks , then you're good.

Answer (score 1):

I have built quite a few small & large crawling systems. Actually not sure what kind of security risks you are talking about. I am not clear on your requirements.

But if all you are doing is fetch the html using BeautifulSoup & then extracting certain stuff about the page like `title` tag & `meta` tag info etc. & then store this data. I dont see any problems.

Unless you are not blindly doing some kind of `eval` either on the response of the url or on the stuff the user entered you are safe I feel.